# twitter4j 4.0.2 getRawJSON() returns null

Tags: java, json, twitter4j

I'm trying to save the tweets I got as JSON objects and however still unable to get the JSON object out of `Status` objects.
I have checked `JSONStoreEnabled()` and it's set to true.

API says,

> Note that raw JSON forms can be retrieved only from the same thread
>   invoked the last method call and will become inaccessible once another
>   method call.

I have my everything inside the main() method, so I guess this shouldn't be an issue.

```
String tweet = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON( status );
```

I have checked that the `status` object contains all the information and it's just that `getRawJSON` returns null!.
Really appreciate if someone can tell me a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it.

```
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         String json = gson.toJson( status );
         System.out.println( json );
```

Comment: I got stuck using TwitterObjectFactory's methods and it gave me null every time I wanted to convert a Status to a string. But your method worked really well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this approach in my own app. You can try this while configuring Twitter4j.

**Using com.google.gson.Gson;**

```
public Gson gson = new Gson();

    ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    config.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    config.setOAuthConsumerKey(Keys.TWITTER_KEY);
    config.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Keys.TWITTER_SECRET);
    config.setOAuthAccessToken(currentSession.getAuthToken().token);
    config.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(currentSession.getAuthToken().secret);
    Configuration cf        = config.build();

// For Twitter4j
enter code here
String statusJson = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status); // status to json
```

Comment: could you pls explain mroe? are you using this with Twitter4j? what is the json, Tweet and tempTweet variables?

Comment: json is the raw json string which you want to convert to Tweet object . I have edited the variables names for clarity. please check.

Comment: If you are using Fabric API then use Tweet object otherwise use Status object for twitter4j

Comment: I have tried,   Status tweet = gson.fromJson( status.toString() , Status.class );   String json = gson.toJson( tweet );      System.out.println( json ); but gives me an exception? Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface twitter4j.Status. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this

Comment: Are you still getting null message ?

Comment: it throws an exception when i'm executing the code (Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface twitter4j.Status. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
new twitter4j.JSONObject(status)
```

it is works for me